# Trying to center navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I start to learn css in the last week, now im trying to make a nav bar. Im trying to position it in the center but want the background will take 100% of the page.

[image: navbar screenshot]

Here's my code:

```css
a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navarea {
  background-color: brown;
}

.navarea:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.navarea ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.navarea>ul>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.navarea ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
}

.navarea ul li:hover a {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.navarea ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 160px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
}

.navarea ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.navarea ul ul li:hover a {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}
```

Comment: dont write a navbar by using `float`. Go with modern techniques such as flexbox (standard since 2015). Then center the navigation elements by using `justify-content: center;` on the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

The modern standard approach (since 2015) is to use `Flexbox` instead of the `float` hack. `float` is intended to be used to float images withing paragraphs. Every other use can be considered a hack and is not necessary since 2012 with the introduction of Grid and Flexbox (which is well supported since 2015).

Use `flex-direction: row;` to line them up horizontally just liek float. To center them in the horizontal center you can use: `justify-content: center;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed to use float. I’m in css lessons and it was needed to learn. Thank you guys!